# How to get data from another different ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Is it possible to auto populate data from a search to a two different ModelForm ?
What I want to do is when I "search" using a GET Method, it shows the Asset details, after the query. the page shows the Asset details with a "Assign" button, when pressed it passes on the "asset_id" and goes to the next HTML create form(LoanerForm). My problem is that on the LoanerForm does not auto populate the "asset_number". I dont get why, the pk is correct and I pass it on as instance on the Form. The other fields updates except the "asset_number" remains the default select option.

My View:

```
def loaner_view_page(request):
asset = request.GET.get('q')
my_asset = Asset.objects.filter(asset_number=asset)

print('Printing results', request.GET)
context = {
    'asset':my_asset,
}
return render(request, 'assets/asset_loaner_page.html', context)

def loaner_assign(request, pk):
asset = Asset.objects.get(id=pk)
form = LoanerForm(instance=asset)
if form.is_valid():
    print('Printing results', request.POST)
    form.save()
    return redirect('/Dashboard/')
context = {
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'assets/asset_loaner_assign.html', context)
```

My Model:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
model_item = models.ForeignKey(Model_Items, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
po_number = models.ForeignKey(Po, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
asset_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
asset_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')#primary device owner/loaner

def __str__(self):
    return self.asset_number

class Loaner(models.Model):
loaner = models.ForeignKey(Asset, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
return_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
```

My HTML:

```
{% for my_asset in asset %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ my_asset.asset_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ my_asset.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ my_asset.serial_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ my_asset.asset_location }}</td>
                <td>{{ my_asset.asset_type }}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'asset_loaner_assign' my_asset.id %}">Assign</a> </td>
           {% endfor %}
            </tr>
```

My Form:

```
class AssetForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Asset
    fields = ('__all__')


class LoanerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Loaner
        fields = ('__all__')
```

My URL:

```
path('Asset_Loaner/', loaner_view_page, name="asset_loaner"),
path('Asset_Loaner_Assign/<str:pk>/', loaner_assign, name="asset_loaner_assign"),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form = LoanerForm(initial={'loaner': pk})
```

Fixed it by using initial instead of instance.